# Why do these syscalls do nothing?

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

I have to write some shellcode, and there's one part that doesn't work:

```
   0:   b0 c9                   mov    $0xc9,%al
   2:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
   4:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
   6:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
   8:   b0 cb                   mov    $0xcb,%al
   a:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

It's the equivalent of `setreuid(geteuid(),geteuid())` (at least I hope it is). It doesn't crash the program or mess anything up, the problem is it doesn't do *anything*. For example, I put shellcode that executes /bin/sh after this and /bin/sh executes fine. Any setuid related syscalls seem to have absolutely no effect.

When I run strace, it outputs:

```
syscall_4294957257(0, 0x8048552, 0xffffd875, 0xf7fc7000, 0xf7fc7000, 0xffffd618) = -1 (errno 38)
syscall_4294967243(0xffffffda, 0xffffffda, 0xffffd875, 0xf7fc7000, 0xf7fc7000, 0xffffd618) = -1 (errno 38)
execve("/bin//sh", NULL, NULL)          = 0
```

I get the same output for `setuid(id)` and `getuid()`. So what I am wondering is why strace recognises execve as execve, but not the others. Shouldn't strace just recognise `setreuid`?

Comment: You only set `al` not `eax`. Presumably the top bits contain some garbage from earlier. Actually `4294957257=0xFFFFD8C9` so you can see the garbage.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. `xor %eax, %eax` after each syscall fixed it.

Comment: *before* each `mov` to `%al` is what you really need; in actual shellcode you can't depend on `%eax` being zero on entry to your payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linux syscall reads the syscall number from the EAX register under x86. By moving C9 into AL, you're only setting the bottom 8 bits of EAX, leaving garbage in the rest. That's why strace calls what you did "syscall_4294957257": It's FFFFD8C9 in hex. (note that it ends with C9.) It's also why you see that `errno 38`, which translates to `ENOSYS` "function not implemented", or in other words, "I don't know what you're asking me to do".

The solution is to to clear `eax` before setting `al`, like so:

```
31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
b0 c9                   mov    al,0xc9
```